# Android phonegap. When I change html nothing changes on emulator

Tags: android, cordova

I followed the helloworld tutorial and I duly got helloworld to appear in the emulator - yay.

I then changed the index.html to the code in the accelerometer sample. I expected it to either fail or work. i.e. I might need a manifest change or something else to explore.

Neither really happened I just keep getting helloworld. I even edited index.html and put "hello world 2" in the html and I got no change.

It just seems intent on putting helloworld up and not running the latest version.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World 2</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check that the recent app is getting deployed. remove the old app from the emulator once and try again

Comment: Check the logs it is possible your updated .apk is failing to install or perhaps Eclipse is not detecting a change in the project. You should be able to force a rebuild by doing a refresh.

Comment: Thanks guys. I don't really know what was going on. Eclipse is a bit of a mystery to me after using visualstudio. I did manage to get it working but you were both right and looking at the logs helped. Why the APK wasn't going to the emulator I don't understand. If anyone else is just starting out with phonegap - I suggest trying the more detailed example and just use the sample.

Comment: @RogerHills If you have understood the reason then please write solution in answer box below so that others can also be benefited by your answer. Also if possible then write a bit about how you found the problem.